# Implicit declaration/conflicting types for 'warning' while compiling a basic sample (hoc1) yacc program

Tags: c, freebsd, yacc, c89, ansi-c

I am following the classic Kernighan & Pike *The Unix Programming Environment*; specifically the chapter that covers *yacc*.
In the first example, a basic calculator named *hoc1* is prepared with *yacc*.

Following the book I prepare the following code:

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
%}
%token NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%
list:
    | list '\n'
    | list expr '\n'    { printf("\t%.8g\n", $2); }
    ;
expr:     NUMBER        { $$ = $1; }
    | expr '+' expr     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '-' expr     { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expr '*' expr     { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expr '/' expr     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | '(' expr ')'      { $$ = $2; }
    ;
%%

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char    *progname;
int lineno = 1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    progname = argv[0];
    yyparse();
    
}


int yylex(void) {

    int c;
    
    /* Left trim all spaces/tabs */
    while((c=getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t');
    
    /* Return 0 if EOF */
    if(c== EOF) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* Return NUMBER if number */
    if(c=='.' || isdigit(c)) {
        ungetc(c,stdin);
        scanf("%lf", &yylval);
        return NUMBER;
    }
    
    /* Count lines */
    if(c=='\n') {
        lineno++;
    }
    
    return c;       
    
}

void yyerror(char *s) {
    
    warning(s, (char *)0);

}

void warning(char *s, char *t) {

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s", progname, s);
    if(t) {
        fprintf(stderr, " %s", t);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, " near line %d\n", lineno);

}
```

But I get the following error while compiling the program:

```
~/tutorials/unix_programming_environment/hoc1 % yacc hoc1.y

~/tutorials/unix_programming_environment/hoc1 % cc y.tab.c -o hoc1

hoc1.y:64:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'warning' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        warning(s, (char *)0);
        ^
hoc1.y:68:6: error: conflicting types for 'warning'
void warning(char *s, char *t) {
     ^
hoc1.y:64:2: note: previous implicit declaration is here
        warning(s, (char *)0);
        ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

I do not understand neither the warning or the error.

Edit: using yacc in FreeBSD 12.1

Comment: @zwol: Why do you think the problem is a bug in `yacc` rather than that they have not declared `warning` before using it?

Comment: Remember that the book was published in 1984, long before there was a standard C.  There wasn't reliably a `void` type then either.   There was no `<stdlib.h>` either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oops. I didn't notice the scrollbar so I thought the bad code was coming from the parser skeleton.

Comment: Actually the book uses the K&R style (which I have never used). So I tried to adapt the example to ANSI C89.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the definition of the `yyerror` function after the definition of the `warning` function or put this line before the `yyerror` function:

```
void warning(char *, char *);
```

This compiler message:

```
hoc1.y:64:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'warning' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

tells you that the function `warning` is being used before any declaration of it is seen. This results in an implicit declaration due to the history of the C language.

This compiler message:

```
hoc1.y:68:6: error: conflicting types for 'warning'
```

tells you that the actual definition of `warning` has a different type than that of the implicit declaration from above.

This solution to this is to declare `warning` before using it, which you can do either by putting the definition (which is a declaration) before the use or by putting a separate declaration before the use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helped me to understand what was actually going on.